# How can I make a shape move in direction of mouse click at a constant speed?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to make a shape move in the direction of a mouse click for a certain distance. I have tried creating variables for the x and y of the mouse on-click event and the distance needed in x and y to get to the mouse click position and dividing + trunc the values to make the shape move in that direction using a timer, although my problem is I need the shape to move a specific distance no matter where the cursor is, just using the mouse click for direction, as well as the shape won't move at a constant speed using this method.

Current code:
on mouse down:

```
mx := x;
my := y;
```

Timer:

```
shape1.left := shape1.Left + (mx - shape1.left + 8) div 32;
shape1.top := shape1.top + (my - shape1.top + 8) div 32;
```

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to include the code you have sofar.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. One question more, what is the specific distance?

Comment: So you need this shape to move with constant speed once it was defined by mouse click? Then compute your speed, vx and vy (x and y components) when mouse is clicked and save them. In each timer event do shape1.left := shape1.left + vx; shape1.top := shape1.top + vy;

Comment: Probably, on mouseclick event you should write vx := (x - shape1.left + 8) div 32;  vy := (y - shape1.top + 8) div 32;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following takes into account distance and constant speed, and uses floats for calculation for better accuracy.

Declared in the form:

```
private
  mx, my: integer; // mouse down
  Steps: integer;
  StepCount: integer;
  OrgPos: TPoint;  // original position
  TrgPos: TPoint;  // target position at angle and distance from orig. pos.
  DeltaX: single;  // x movement per step
  DeltaY: single;  // y movement per step
```

The forms OnMouseDown:

```
var
  angle: single;
  dx, dy: single;
  dist: single;
begin
  mx := X;
  my := Y;
  Steps := 32;
  StepCount := 0;
  dist := 100.0;
  // shape origin
  OrgPos.X := Shape1.Left;
  OrgPos.Y := Shape1.Top;
  // get the angle
  dx := Abs(mx - OrgPos.X);
  if dx = 0 then dx := 0.00000001;
  dy := Abs(my - OrgPos.Y);
  if dy = 0 then dy := 0.00000001;
  angle := arctan(dy/dx);
  // correction for quadrant
  if (OrgPos.X>mx) and (OrgPos.Y<my) then angle := Pi-angle;
  if (OrgPos.X>mx) and (OrgPos.Y>my) then angle := Pi+angle;
  if (OrgPos.X<mx) and (OrgPos.Y>my) then angle := 2*Pi-angle;
  // endpoint based on angle and distance
  TrgPos.X := round(OrgPos.X + dist*cos(angle));
  TrgPos.Y := round(OrgPos.Y + dist*sin(angle));
  // x and y changes per step
  DeltaX := (TrgPos.X - OrgPos.X) / Steps;
  DeltaY := (TrgPos.Y - OrgPos.Y) / Steps;
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;
```

The timer code:

```
  Inc(StepCount);
  Shape1.Left := OrgPos.X + Round(StepCount * DeltaX);
  Shape1.Top := OrgPos.Y + Round(StepCount * DeltaY);
  if StepCount >= Steps then
    Timer1.Enabled := False;
```

Calculating the new position as `OrgPos.X + Round(StepCount * DeltaX);` prevents cascading errors.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your approach is that the amount you move per unit time is proportional to the distance between the shape and your mouse click location. All you need from the mouse location is a direction and the standard way to get a direction is to normalize the vector formed between the points of interest.

Dividing by the magnitude of the line segment formed between the points of interest produces a unit vector with a length of 1px in the direction you want to go.  This must then be scaled by a speed to produce an increment of motion.

This is clumsy to do with integers since your increments must be rounded at each step, but it can be done as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
const
  SPEED = 5;
var
  dx, dy : integer;
  mag : double;
begin
  dx := mx - Shape1.Left;                           {vector x}
  dy := my - Shape1.Top;                            {vector y}
  mag := Sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);                       {vector magnitude}  
  if (Abs(dx) > SPEED) or (Abs(dy) > SPEED) then 
  begin
    { use Ceil to move at least 1px. }
    Shape1.Left := Shape1.Left 
                   + Sign(dx)*Ceil(SPEED*Abs(dx)/mag);  {divide by mag}
    Shape1.Top := Shape1.Top                            {to give a unit}
                   + Sign(dy)*Ceil(SPEED*Abs(dy)/mag);  {vector in the}   
  end else begin                                        {required direction}
    Shape1.Left := mx;        {snap to mx/my if close enough}
    Shape1.Top := my;         {deals with rounding issues...}  
  end;
end;
```

Otherwise, more elegantly, you can store your shape's position in a floating point pair and round to an integer only when setting the control's location.  This avoids integer precision issues with each step along the way.

Comment: @User049 Anything is possible.  It should be clear how to do that if you understand what this answer is doing.

Comment: @User049 Sounds like a good idea.  You know, from above, how to get a unit vector in the right direction and how to scale it to make a step... it should be straightforward to place your target whatever distance away you want.

Comment: @User049 Think about it - your `MouseDown` handler will look almost exactly the same as the code above.  Replace `mx` with `x`, `my` with `y`, and Shape1's `.Left` and `.Top` for `mx` and `my`.  Now `SPEED` becomes `DISTANCE` and you can pick whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

no need for using the timer . you can move the shape if the left button of the mouse are pressed .

```
var
 LeftMousePressed2 : Boolean ;
 X_original,Y_original : cardinal ;
```

when you create the form .

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 LeftMousePressed2 := false ;
end;
```

here you get the original coordinates of the mouse

```
procedure TForm1.Shape1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
   Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
if Button = mbLeft then
begin
   X_original:=x;
   Y_original:=y;
   LeftMousePressed2 := true ;
end;
```

when moving (the mouse + left button pressed ) then the shape move also :

```
procedure TForm1.Shape1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y : Integer);
begin
if LeftMousePressed2 then
begin
  shape1.Left := Shape1.Left +(x-X_original);
  shape1.Top := shape1.Top + (y-Y_original);
end;
end;
```

When lifting the finger from the mouse

```
procedure TForm1.Shape1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;Shift: 
 TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
 begin
 LeftMousePressed2 := false ;
 end;
```